# Bootstrap 3 is broken on Win 7 IE Version - 8.0.7600.16385

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 is not working or broken on Win 7 IE Version - 8.0.7600.16385

URL : http://getbootstrap.com/

It seems the respond.js or html5shiv is not working on this specific version of IE 8. But its working fine on IE v8.0.7601 and IE v8.0.6001 (Via Sauce labs)

Here is the HTML (head part) All files are on correct path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>OHH Web App</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="media/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Structure: Global -->
<link href="media/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Modernizr (Should be on Head)-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 Shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Any Idea how to fix this? or is this a known bug in this version? Thanks for your help

Attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Try remove HTML5 and try?

Comment: @Gorostas That didn't help. No change

Answer (score 0):

HTML5.js only wokr on server side, but sometimes its get problem with some other scripts. please check your CSS properties, and if that does not help. try add manually some script to force html5 elements, like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
var e = ("abbr,article,aside,audio,canvas,datalist,details,
figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,
progress,section,time,video,figcaption,summary").split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    document.createElement(e[i]);
}
<![endif]-->
```

Please check does evrything works in ie8, and check any error logs, maybe some script is forcing the problem.If you are didint sure about your css, please check this

http://css3pie.com/

It can help you a lot properly write your css for older browsers

Comment: Hi, I have not used any HTML5 tags. Only Div's. Also this issue is only on that specific version 8.0 7600. Its working perfect on 8.0 7601. Even the bootstrap site has the same problem. http://getbootstrap.com/ I guess its a browser bug. What do you think?